# Choosing between oblivion, forgetfulness, and forgetting

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

I am trying to figure out what is the right word related to *forgetting* in this quote by Blasco Ibáñez:

> *Tenemos dos fuerzas que nos ayudan a vivir: el olvido y la esperanza.*

which translated in English would be as below (that is how someone [posted it via Reddit here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tattoos/comments/f16ycj/we_have_two_forces_that_help_us_to_live_oblivion/) and how Google Translate translates it):

> *We have two forces that help us to live: oblivion and hope.*

---

However, I am wondering if *oblivion* is the right word. This question is not so much about translating *olvido* from Spanish ot English, but finding the right English word.

*Olvidar* means *to forget* and *olvido* is the noun referring to the fact that memories fade away.

I am unsure about the English term (one word) that would fit here: *oblivion*, *forgetfulness* or simply *forgetting*?

Since I have never used *oblivion* before, I looked it in the dictionary and its very definition is quite powerful for this context:

> the state of being unaware or unconscious of what is happening around one

I would use *forgetting and hope* instead, but would it be correct? What about *forgetfulness*?

Is there a better term for the fact that we, as humans, forget memories (such as sufferings, happy moments etc)?

Comment: You need to tell us what olvido actually means — how it is used in example sentences translated into English. This is poetry or the like — some sort of paradox — so knowing no Spanish we cannot deduce what the writer intends. Oblivion as in "death"? Or forgetting (weak in English, and forgetfulness is unlikely to sound other than trite) in the sense that bitter memories fade?

Comment: @David _Olvidar_ means _to forget_. _Olvido_ is the substantive, but Google Translate translates it as _oblivion_ which is a word I have never used before...

Comment: @David I think the fact I am not sure is: what is the substantive that reflects the fact that we, humans, _forget_ memories?

Comment: Oxford Languages defines _oblivion_ as _the state of being unaware or unconscious of what is happening around one._ That hardly goes with 'being helped to live'.

Comment: We have a [spanish.se] site, which might be better for this. It's going to be full of Spanish speakers who will know the exact meaning of olvido.

Comment: @DJClayworth I know the meaning of _olvido_, I just don't know the difference between _oblivion_, _forgetfulness_, and _forgetting_... Hehe!

Comment: Well the only direct substantive of forget in English is the participle, forgetting, which would sound odd as a translation. I would imagine that to make it English you would have to change “forces” to “things” or “factors” (or something better), reverse the order, and use a phrase like “the fact that memories fade”.

Comment: @David Would _forgetting and hope_ be incorrect? _Fuerzas_ literally means _forces_...

Comment: I can't see 'forgetfulness' as being in any way relevant to a proverb about coping wth life's hardships. I can't find the source of quote, but I could see it as something said by a person in a desperate situation. 'Oblivion' has the necessary punch, if it's about the struggle to survive: more than say passing an exam, or getting the shopping done.

Comment: Although I'd enjoy discussing translation (and I do have French and Italian and a wee bit of Spanish) this isn't really the forum. If I had an idea for a single word I'd post it as an answer, but we shouldn't use comments for this.

Comment: Welcome! There are many comments here that have clarified the question, but please use the "edit" button to update the question itself; as it stands, it doesn't meet [the standards for on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it doesn't show that you've looked these words up in a dictionary. And since translation isn't a topic covered here, the question should focus on the difference between the three suggested words, rather than which best translates *olvido*.

Comment: (Now I'm confused—is *oblivion* not a legitimate Spanish word? It's the title of a Piazzolla tango... but from what I can tell, all dictionaries recommend translating it as *olvido*)

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. In short, I am unsure if _forgetting_ would be a good word choice, while _oblivion_ seems to be way more powerful than _forgetting_.

Comment: Grrrgh to google translate botches. It's forgetting. **Note to other participants: the other language sites are not for translation into English. They are for translation into another language**. However, only the French site is strict about this, afaik.

Comment: @Lambie I also thought that this would be the right side to post the question. And for clarity I chose to add the original quote (in Spanish), just for reference, but that seems that confused us even more... Hehe... :-)

Comment: Right. You can go with forgetting. Forgetfulness is for your grandmother as she ages and doesn't remember everything right away. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău I think (but don't know) a better direct translation of *el olvido* for the context would be 'obliviousness'.   Also, Mitch has it, but it's buried in his answer.  Not just 'forgetting', but 'the ability to forget'.

Comment: Cross-post? https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/40402/translating-olvido-y-esperanza-in-english

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm not sure why there is distaste for cross-posting on SE, but in this particular instance, the two communities have very low overlap and are likely to produce two different selections of answers which is where cross-posting works best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oblivion** might work, as long as the connotations line up with the Spanish *olvidar* in a way that satisfies your sensibilities as a translator. Otherwise, **forgetting** is laden with fewer negative connotations and may be a suitable literal term.

### Oblivion

The issue with **oblivion** in English is that some of its meanings have negative connotations. For instance, the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/129744) defines *oblivion* definition 1a and 1b as:

> 1a. The state or fact of forgetting or having forgotten; forgetfulness; (also) freedom from care or worry.
>
> 1b. Forgetfulness resulting from inattention or carelessness; heedlessness, disregard.

1b poses a problem. *Oblivion* can be seen as a kind of carelessness or inattention, which goes beyond memories fading with time. That is not to mention the destructive connotation:

> 2a. The state or condition of being forgotten; (also, more generally) obscurity, nothingness, void, death.

The idea of falling into oblivion, that is, dying or being entirely forgot, is a part of the word. So you would want to make sure that *olvidar* has similar connotations or that you're okay with your translation having that be a possible reading.

### Other possibilities

**Forgetfulness** runs into a similar issue that **oblivion** did; it may suggest a negative mental capacity or a negative moral quality (see definition 1b above). In my experience, that sense is even stronger with *forgetfulness* than with *oblivion*. Definition 4 of the word gives a particularly strong example:

> 4. Disregard, inattention, neglect.
>
> 1757   S. Johnson Rambler No. 180. ⁋5   He..naturally sinks from omission to **forgetfulness** of social duties.

For that reason, I would suggest avoiding it.

**Forgetting** is an attractive word to use in this context. It is close to the verb and hence closer to the basic sense *to forget*, with fewer negative connotations. It also has precedent in William Wordsworth's *[Ode on Intimations of Immortality](https://poets.org/poem/ode-intimations-immortality-recollections-early-childhood)*:

> Our birth is but a sleep and a **forgetting**;
>
> The Soul that rises with us, our life's Star,
>
> Hath had elsewhere its setting
>
> And cometh from afar [...]

So poetry can combine forms that might be odd in other contexts: "a sleep and a forgetting" or "forgetting and hope."

Comment: If going with the option of "forgetting", I'd go with "We have two forces that help us to live: hoping, and forgetting." for the parallel structure. Maybe not "forces", but I don't know what word would fit there better now.

Comment: I think a better translation of olvido is obliviousness.  What are your thoughts on that vis-a-vis oblivion?

Comment: @mcalex In English, "obliviousness" means "not noticing something that's there" rather than "forgetting something", so it doesn't fit the statement as I understand it.

Comment: There's somewhat of a wilful connotation to it, however - seeing and choosing to not notice.  Arguably instant forgetting.

Answer (score 5):

- ['oblivion'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivion) is a very strong negative, and is rarer than the other two, and is a much more academic word than the others. It means a total eradication from everyone's memory. It is often associated with total destruction or annihilation, to the extent that no one remembers the thing destroyed any more.
- ['forgetting'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forget) is a past participle or gerund, so it is very verb like. It is not common as a gerund (noun). Note that it doesn't have its own  dictionary entry, coming under 'forget', but can still stand alone as the abstract noun for 'the process of losing memories'.
- ['forgetfulness'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forgetfulness) is half suffixes, is common, and often taken to be a symptom of old-age or a deficiency.

'Oblivion' is not recommended even if it is the accepted translation of 'el olvido', since 'oblivion' is so extreme in English. Is 'totally forgetting everything about something' really a 'force that helps us live'? That seems a little weird to pair with hope and also you don't often think of oblivion (total loss of a memories of a thing) to be a positive. Maybe just the ability to forget little would be enough.

So in a pair along with 'hope', the most parallel would be 'forgetfulness', but 'forgetting' may also be appropriate since its association is just the process and not a slightly negative

Comment: I associate "oblivion" with forgetting even one's self, becoming completely lost. For me, it's connected with death-sans-afterlife, lobotomies, drug use, and other unhealthy ways of making bad memories not relevant to your present situation.

Answer (score 3):

I take the quote to mean that what drives us forward in life, is both the promise of something better (hope), and *the forgetting of suffering and other evidence to the contrary.*
In that last sense it feels slightly analogous to the proverb "ignorance is bliss", but ignorance doesn't seem to come close to the intended meaning of Blasco Ibáñez.

I think of the three *forgetting* is the best option:

- *Forgetfulness* implies a more active loss of memory. It is only really used when someone has a relatively higher tendency to forget things.
- *Oblivion* is a state of being completely forgotten. It is what has happened to most people throughout our history (and, necessarily, before that), so certainly not an impetus to live.
- *Forgetting* comes closest, and, although it might not be sufficiently precise as anything can be forgotten, for the sake of lucidity (of the aphorism) this seems the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Between your three options, I would rank them forgetting best, oblivion worst. If you're willing to use a phrase rather than single word, you could say "impermanence of memory" or "imperfect memory". There's also "amnesia", but that implies a state of being more forgetful than normal, and this saying seems to be saying that normal human forgetfulness is helpful.

Comment: +1 for "amnesia", which while not literally correct would probably be interpreted correctly in a poetic context like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, oblivion is a state, forgetfulness is a personal rather than universal property and forgetting is an action.  Neither work very well as a force.  I find that I fail to come up with a good single term, so in the course of making a viable literary dichotomy, I'd use "We have two forces helping us survive: weakness of memory and strength of hope."